# XMLHttprequest.send(null) is crashing my code

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I'm currently writing a search function using JavaScript.

However, when I attempt to test my creation, I find that it stops about halfway through for no discernible reason.

Below is my code:

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "";
var Connect = new XMLHttpRequest();
Connect.open("GET", "xmlTest.xml", false);
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "1";
Connect.send(null);
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "2";
var docX = Connect.responseXML;
var linjer = docX.getElementsByTagName("linjer");
```

The first line is there to clear a potential error message from earlier in the code. Then I attempt to open up an XML file, as I need to read from it.

As you can see, I've entered two debug statements there; they will print 1 or 2 depending on how far I get in the code.

Using this, I've found that it stops exactly on the `Connect.send(null);` statement (as 1 gets printed, but 2 never does), but I can't figure out why. Google says that it might be that chrome can't access local files, but when I found a way to allow Chrome to do this, it still did not work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried sending nothing `.send()` or an empty string `.send("")` ?

Comment: Well you disabled async, and since your code stops at the send function, there must be trouble finding that local file.

Comment: What does the Developer Tools console and net tab say?

Comment: P.S. AJAX is *asynchronous*.  Your `Connect.responseXML` will be blank.  You need to use a *callback* to get that value once the AJAX call is done.

Comment: @RocketHazmat That is not an asynchronous call.

Comment: Where is this page running from?  Where is `xmlTest.xml` located?  EDIT: Are you sure it *stops*?   Maybe it's just loading the file.  Since you set this to a non-async call, `.send()` will *freeze* and *lock up* until the file is loaded.

Comment: @epascarello: Yes, you're right.  I didn't notice the `false` parameter to `.open()`.

Comment: So you are running on the file protocol and you started Chome with `--allow-file-access-from-files`?

Comment: I have tried with .send() and .send(""), neither works.

Googling the error makes it seem that the browser somehow can't find my xml file... I doublechecked that the name is correct though.

I have no idea what the developer tools say... I'm using the Brackets tool, and I don't know where the error logs are. Not sure what you mean by net tab either, I'm very very new to this.

The page is running locally, as I don't have a server to test it on. The xml file is uploaded to the same folder as the html page (and css and javascript files).

Comment: The XML file is tiny; I'm just using a dummy file for testing right now with like three layers of tags. 

I have attempted to start chrome with the --allow-file-access-from-files thing, but it did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a synchronous issue that requires a response that your code simply is not getting.

Try using an async call instead:

```
Connect.open("GET", "xmlTest.xml", true);
```

Also make sure to setup proper callbacks since you'll be using async here now instead of synchronous code, like so:

```
// Global variable scope
var docX;
var linjer;

// Define your get function
getDoc = function(url, cbFunc) {

    var Connect = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // Perform actions after request is sent
    // You'll insert your callback here
    Connect.onreadystatechange = function() {
        // 4 means request finished and response is ready
        if ( Connect.readyState == 4 ) {
            // Here is where you do the callback
            cbFunc(Connect.responseXML);
        } 
    }; 

    // 'true' param means async, it is also the default
    Connect.open('GET', url, true);
    Connect.send();
}

// Define your callback function    
callbackFunction = function(responseXML) {
    // XML file can now be stored in the global variable
    window.docX = responseXML;
    window.linjer = window.docX.getElementsByTagName("linjer");
}

// And here is the call you make to do this
getDoc("xmlTest.xml", callbackFunction);
```

For better understanding of all of this, do some research on **scope**, **closures**, **callbacks**, and **async**.

Comment: This seems to have worked! I do not have the slightest clue what the proper callbacks are though... Where do I find those?

EDIT: Okay, so, it kinda works. It makes the debug statement number 2 appear, but it then stops again at 

    var docX = Connect.responseXML;

Comment: @TheJack38 updated, please let me know if this works out for you

Comment: Is this everything that needs to be done for it to work properly? Do I have to set up anything else inside the callback function?

Comment: @TheJack38 you need to edit the callback to your needs, what ever you do with that response is up to you. So you are grabbing XML, in the callback you need to define what you want to do with that XML data

Comment: So basically I can just copypaste this code, and hten just make the callbackFunction(response) do whatever I want to do with the response normally. Yeah, I'll see if this works, thanks! (I have to go to class quick, so I can't test it right now)

Comment: @TheJack38 assigning docX needs to go into the callback. I also made some specific edits for XML. Check the code out, it's working fine on my end